# Cancancan check submitted parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cancancan

How do I get cancancan to check an parameter to see if the user can update?

Controller gets:

```
Parameters: {"offer"=>{"revoked"=>"1", "user_id"=>"14"}, "id"=>"53"}
```

ability.rb:

```
can :update, Controller, :user_id => user.id
cannot :update, Controller, { :revoked => nil }
```

controller code:

```
@offer.update(params)
```

This is giving me a Cancancan error saying that the user is not authorized.  I think I need to specify that :revoked is inside the offer hash, but I can't figure out the correct code for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to change what the Ability class can access:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Accessing-Request-Data

Or how to pass params into the Ability class more specifically for your purposes:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9472881/4880924

> ```
> # CanCan - pass params in to Ability
> # https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/133
> def current_ability
>     @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user, params)
> end
> ```

Then it's a matter of simply accessing the relevant part of the params and checking whether it passes.