# Rails Cancancan authorization of models in many-to-many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, authorization, many-to-many, cancancan

I have *User* and *Role* models in many-to-many relations via *UserRoleAssoc* in Ruby-on-Rails.

I need a page (web interface) from which a user can add/delete roles associated with a user, where ordinary users but administrators can *edit* the roles for themselves only.

My question is how to implement the scheme, particularly authorization.

Here are the models of *User* and *Role* (just the standard many-to-many):

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_role_assocs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :roles, through: :user_role_assocs
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_role_assocs
  has_many :users, through: :user_role_assocs
end

class UserRoleAssoc < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

According to DHH's principle (cf. "[How DHH Organizes His Rails Controllers](http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/)" by Jerome Dalbert), such actions should be implemented as if a controller, say, `ManageUserRolesController`, does one or more of the CRUD actions. In this case, `ManageUserRolesController` either or both of `create` and `delete` multiple records on `UserRoleAssoc`.

Since the web user interface should enable one to manage a list of roles (with a select box) in one go from a URL, I made the `create` method of `ManageUserRolesController` does both, receiving User-ID (`user`) and an Array of Role-IDs (`roles`) in `params` (I'm open to suggestions, though!). `routes.rb` is as follows:

```rb
resources :manage_user_role, only: [:create]  # index may be provided, too.
```

Now, to restrict a user to add/delete roles to any other users, I would like to write in `models/ability.rb` something like, along with a Controller:

```rb
 # models/ability.rb`
can :create, ManageUserRoles, :PARAMS => {user: user}  # "PARAMS" is invalid!! Any alternative ideas?
can :manage, ManageUserRoles if user.administrator?

 # controllers/manage_user_roles_controller.rb
class ManageUserRolesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

It seems possible to achieve it in the way described in an answer to "[Passing params to CanCan in RoR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9472881/3577922)" and [CanCan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Accessing-Request-Data), though I think the model corresponding to the controller has to be defined to point the non-standard table, in `models/manage_user_role.rb`

```rb
class ManageUserRole < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'user_role_assocs'
end
```

But this seems quite awkward…
What is the 'Rails' way (Version 6+) to implement authorization of many-to-many models? To be specific, what is a good interface to add/delete multiple roles to a user with some constraint?

Note that the route doesn't have to be like the sample code above; the route can be set so that a user-ID is passed as a part of the path like `/manage_user_role/:user_id` instead of via `params`, as long as authorization works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer, a solution I have used in the end.

### Background

Many-to-many relation is by definition complex and I do not think there are any simple solutions that fit all cases. Certainly, Ability in CanCanCan does not support it in default (unless you do some complicated hacks, such as the way the OP wanted to avoid, as mentioned in the Question).

In this particular case of question, however, the situation which the OP wants to deal with is a constraint based on the user ID, which is basically a one-to-many (or `has_many`) relation, namely one-user having many roles. Then, it can actually fit in the standard way as Cancancan/Ability works.

General speaking, there are three ways to deal with the OP's case of many-to-many relation between users and roles (*i.e.*, each user can have many roles and a role may belong to many users):

1. handling it as in the User (Controller) model,
2. handling it as in the Role (Controller) model,
3. or UserRoleAssoc (Controller), that is, a model associated with the join table between User and Role (*n.b.*, this Controller is not created by default and so you must create it manually if you use it).

Let me discuss below which one of the three best fits the purpose with Cancancan authorization.

### How Cancancan authorizes with Ability and what would fit this case best

For the default CRUD actions, Cancancan deals with a `can` statement as follows (in my understanding); this is basically a brief summary with regard to this case of the [official reference of Cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/tree/develop/docs):

- for the action `index`, only the information Cancancan has is the User, the Model Class (with/without scopes), in addition to the action type `index`. So, basically, Cancancan does not and cannot do much. Importantly, a Ruby block associated with the `can` statement, if any, is **not** called.
- if the (primary) ID of the model is given in the path, namely for the actions of `show`, `edit`, `update`, `destroy`, Cancancan retrieves the model from the DB and it is fed to the algorithm you provide with the `can` statement, including a Ruby block, if given.

In the OP's case, a user should not be authorized to handle the roles of any other users but of her/himself.  Then, the judgement must be based on the two user-IDs, *i.e.*, the one of `current_user` and the one given in the path/route. For Rails to pick up the latter from the path automatically, the route must be set accordingly.

Then, because the "ID" is a User-ID, the most natural solution to deal with this case is to use **UsersController** (case 1 in the description above); then the ID included in the default route is interpreted as `User#id` by Rails and Cancancan.  By contrast, if you adopt case 2, the default ID in the path will be interpreted as `Role#id`, which does not work well with this case. As for case 3 (which was mentioned in the question), `UserRoleAssoc#id` is just a random number given to an association and has nothing to do with `User#id` or `Role#id`. Therefore, it does not fit this case, either.

### Solution

As explained above, the action of the Controller must be selected carefully so that Cancancan correctly sets the User based on the given ID in the path.

The OP mentions `create` and `delete` (`destroy`) for the Controller. It is technically true in this case that the required actions are either or both of to *create* and *delete* new associations between a User and Roles. However, in Rails' default routing, `create` does not take the ID parameter (of course not, given the ID is given in creation by the DB!). Therefore, the action name of `create` is not really appropriate in this case. `update` would be most appropriate. In the natural language, we interpret it such that a user's (Role-association) status will be *update*-d with this action of a Controller. The default HTTP method for `update` is `PATCH/PUT`, which fits the meaning of the operation, too.

Finally, here is the solution I have found to work (with Rails 6.1):

###### routes.rb

```rb
resources :manage_user_roles, only: [:update]
  # => Route: manage_user_role PATCH  /manage_user_roles/:id(.:format)  manage_user_roles#update
```

###### manage_user_roles_controller.rb

```rb
class ManageUserRolesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :user
  # This means as far as authorization is concerned,
  # the model and controller are User and UsersController.
  
  my_params = params.permit('add_role_11', 'del_role_11', 'add_role_12', 'del_role_12')
end
```

###### View (to submit the data)

This can be in `show.html.erb` of User or whatever.

```rb
<%= form_with(method: :patch, url: manage_user_role_path(@user)) do |form| %>
  Form components follow...
```

###### app/models/ability.rb

```rb
def initialize(user)
  if user.present?
    can :update, User, id: user.id
  end
end
```

---

A key take is, I think, simplifying the case. Though many-to-many relations are inherently complex, you probably better deal with each case in smaller and more simple fragments. Then, they may fit in the existing scheme without too much hustle.